# Text Field and Drop Down Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I am new to javascript and am trying to add a combobox to a form I am creating, I would like the user to be able to enter an answer or pick one from a drop down. I found a pluggin online and set it up. The drop down works fine but the answer entered by the user isn't stored in the text field, when you click out of the text box it disappears.

I looking at the onblur part of the code to see if I could change the behavior but I couldn't. Could someone help? the code is below.

My HTML (I'm using Bootstrap)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="input-group">
                              <label for="user_id" class="input-group-addon">User ID</label>
                              <select class="combobox input-large form-control" name="user_id" id="user_id">
                              <option value="" selected="selected">Enter ID</option>
                              <option value="ML">Multiple Users</option>
                              <option value="UN">Unknow User</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>
                      </div>
    </div>
```

And the Javascript

```
    !function( $ ) {

 "use strict";

 /* COMBOBOX PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  * ================================ */

  var Combobox = function ( element, options ) {
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.combobox.defaults, options);
    this.template = this.options.template || this.template
    this.$source = $(element);
    this.$container = this.setup();
    this.$element = this.$container.find('input[type=text]');
    this.$target = this.$container.find('input[type=hidden]');
    this.$button = this.$container.find('.dropdown-toggle');
    this.$menu = $(this.options.menu).appendTo('body');
    this.matcher = this.options.matcher || this.matcher;
    this.sorter = this.options.sorter || this.sorter;
    this.highlighter = this.options.highlighter || this.highlighter;
    this.shown = false;
    this.selected = false;
    this.refresh();
    this.transferAttributes();
    this.listen();
  };

  Combobox.prototype = {

    constructor: Combobox

  , setup: function () {
      var combobox = $(this.template());
      this.$source.before(combobox);
      this.$source.hide();
      return combobox;
    }

  , disable: function() {
      this.$element.prop('disabled', true);
      this.$button.attr('disabled', true);
      this.disabled = true;
      this.$container.addClass('combobox-disabled');
    }

  , enable: function() {
      this.$element.prop('disabled', false);
      this.$button.attr('disabled', false);
      this.disabled = false;
      this.$container.removeClass('combobox-disabled');
    }
  , parse: function () {
      var that = this
        , map = {}
        , source = []
        , selected = false
        , selectedValue = '';
      this.$source.find('option').each(function() {
        var option = $(this);
        if (option.val() === '') {
          that.options.placeholder = option.text();
          return;
        }
        map[option.text()] = option.val();
        source.push(option.text());
        if (option.prop('selected')) {
          selected = option.text();
          selectedValue = option.val();
        }
      })
      this.map = map;
      if (selected) {
        this.$element.val(selected);
        this.$target.val(selectedValue);
        this.$container.addClass('combobox-selected');
        this.selected = true;
      }
      return source;
    }

  , transferAttributes: function() {
    this.options.placeholder = this.$source.attr('data-placeholder') || this.options.placeholder
    this.$element.attr('placeholder', this.options.placeholder)
    this.$target.prop('name', this.$source.prop('name'))
    this.$target.val(this.$source.val())
    this.$source.removeAttr('name')  // Remove from source otherwise form will pass parameter twice.
    this.$element.attr('required', this.$source.attr('required'))
    this.$element.attr('rel', this.$source.attr('rel'))
    this.$element.attr('title', this.$source.attr('title'))
    this.$element.attr('class', this.$source.attr('class'))
    this.$element.attr('tabindex', this.$source.attr('tabindex'))
    this.$source.removeAttr('tabindex')
    if (this.$source.attr('disabled')!==undefined)
      this.disable();
  }

  , select: function () {
      var val = this.$menu.find('.active').attr('data-value');
      this.$element.val(this.updater(val)).trigger('change');
      this.$target.val(this.map[val]).trigger('change');
      this.$source.val(this.map[val]).trigger('change');
      this.$container.addClass('combobox-selected');
      this.selected = true;
      return this.hide();
    }

  , updater: function (item) {
      return item;
    }

  , show: function () {
      var pos = $.extend({}, this.$element.position(), {
        height: this.$element[0].offsetHeight
      });

      this.$menu
        .insertAfter(this.$element)
        .css({
          top: pos.top + pos.height
        , left: pos.left
        })
        .show();

      $('.dropdown-menu').on('mousedown', $.proxy(this.scrollSafety, this));

      this.shown = true;
      return this;
    }

  , hide: function () {
      this.$menu.hide();
      $('.dropdown-menu').off('mousedown', $.proxy(this.scrollSafety, this));
      this.$element.on('blur', $.proxy(this.blur, this));
      this.shown = false;
      return this;
    }

  , lookup: function (event) {
      this.query = this.$element.val();
      return this.process(this.source);
    }

  , process: function (items) {
      var that = this;

      items = $.grep(items, function (item) {
        return that.matcher(item);
      })

      items = this.sorter(items);

      if (!items.length) {
        return this.shown ? this.hide() : this;
      }

      return this.render(items.slice(0, this.options.items)).show();
    }

  , template: function() {
      if (this.options.bsVersion == '2') {
        return '<div class="combobox-container"><input type="hidden" /> <div class="input-append"> <input type="text" autocomplete="off" /> <span class="add-on dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown"> <span class="caret"/> <i class="icon-remove"/> </span> </div> </div>'
      } else {
        return '<div class="combobox-container"> <input type="hidden" /> <div class="input-group"> <input type="text" autocomplete="off" /> <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown"> <span class="caret" /> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" /> </span> </div> </div>'
      }
    }

  , matcher: function (item) {
      return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase());
    }

  , sorter: function (items) {
      var beginswith = []
        , caseSensitive = []
        , caseInsensitive = []
        , item;

      while (item = items.shift()) {
        if (!item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())) {beginswith.push(item);}
        else if (~item.indexOf(this.query)) {caseSensitive.push(item);}
        else {caseInsensitive.push(item);}
      }

      return beginswith.concat(caseSensitive, caseInsensitive);
    }

  , highlighter: function (item) {
      var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
      return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
      })
    }

  , render: function (items) {
      var that = this;

      items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
        i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item);
        i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item));
        return i[0];
      })

      items.first().addClass('active');
      this.$menu.html(items);
      return this;
    }

  , next: function (event) {
      var active = this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active')
        , next = active.next();

      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this.$menu.find('li')[0]);
      }

      next.addClass('active');
    }

  , prev: function (event) {
      var active = this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active')
        , prev = active.prev();

      if (!prev.length) {
        prev = this.$menu.find('li').last();
      }

      prev.addClass('active');
    }

  , toggle: function () {
    if (!this.disabled) {
      if (this.$container.hasClass('combobox-selected')) {
        this.clearTarget();
        this.triggerChange();
        this.clearElement();
      } else {
        if (this.shown) {
          this.hide();
        } else {
          this.clearElement();
          this.lookup();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  , scrollSafety: function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName == 'UL') {
          this.$element.off('blur');
      }
  }
  , clearElement: function () {
    this.$element.val('').focus();
  }

  , clearTarget: function () {
    this.$source.val('');
    this.$target.val('');
    this.$container.removeClass('combobox-selected');
    this.selected = false;
  }

  , triggerChange: function () {
    this.$source.trigger('change');
  }

  , refresh: function () {
    this.source = this.parse();
    this.options.items = this.source.length;
  }

  , listen: function () {
      this.$element
        .on('focus',    $.proxy(this.focus, this))
        .on('blur',     $.proxy(this.blur, this))
        .on('keypress', $.proxy(this.keypress, this))
        .on('keyup',    $.proxy(this.keyup, this));

      if (this.eventSupported('keydown')) {
        this.$element.on('keydown', $.proxy(this.keydown, this));
      }

      this.$menu
        .on('click', $.proxy(this.click, this))
        .on('mouseenter', 'li', $.proxy(this.mouseenter, this))
        .on('mouseleave', 'li', $.proxy(this.mouseleave, this));

      this.$button
        .on('click', $.proxy(this.toggle, this));
    }

  , eventSupported: function(eventName) {
      var isSupported = eventName in this.$element;
      if (!isSupported) {
        this.$element.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
        isSupported = typeof this.$element[eventName] === 'function';
      }
      return isSupported;
    }

  , move: function (e) {
      if (!this.shown) {return;}

      switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 9: // tab
        case 13: // enter
        case 27: // escape
          e.preventDefault();
          break;

        case 38: // up arrow
          e.preventDefault();
          this.prev();
          break;

        case 40: // down arrow
          e.preventDefault();
          this.next();
          break;
      }

      e.stopPropagation();
    }

  , keydown: function (e) {
      this.suppressKeyPressRepeat = ~$.inArray(e.keyCode, [40,38,9,13,27]);
      this.move(e);
    }

  , keypress: function (e) {
      if (this.suppressKeyPressRepeat) {return;}
      this.move(e);
    }

  , keyup: function (e) {
      switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 40: // down arrow
        case 39: // right arrow
        case 38: // up arrow
        case 37: // left arrow
        case 36: // home
        case 35: // end
        case 16: // shift
        case 17: // ctrl
        case 18: // alt
          break;

        case 9: // tab
        case 13: // enter
          if (!this.shown) {return;}
          this.select();
          break;

        case 27: // escape
          if (!this.shown) {return;}
          this.hide();
          break;

        default:
          this.clearTarget();
          this.lookup();
      }

      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
  }

  , focus: function (e) {
      this.focused = true;
    }

  , blur: function (e) {
      var that = this;
      this.focused = false;
      var val = this.$element.val();
      if (!this.selected && val !== '' ) {
        this.$element.val('');
        this.$source.val('').trigger('change');
        this.$target.val('').trigger('change');
      }
      if (!this.mousedover && this.shown) {setTimeout(function () { that.hide(); }, 200);}
    }

  , click: function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      this.select();
      this.$element.focus();
    }

  , mouseenter: function (e) {
      this.mousedover = true;
      this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    }

  , mouseleave: function (e) {
      this.mousedover = false;
    }
  };

  /* COMBOBOX PLUGIN DEFINITION
   * =========================== */
  $.fn.combobox = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('combobox')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
      if(!data) {$this.data('combobox', (data = new Combobox(this, options)));}
      if (typeof option == 'string') {data[option]();}
    });
  };

  $.fn.combobox.defaults = {
    bsVersion: '3'
  , menu: '<ul class="typeahead typeahead-long dropdown-menu"></ul>'
  , item: '<li><a href="#"></a></li>'
  };

  $.fn.combobox.Constructor = Combobox;

}( window.jQuery );
```

Binding the function to class 'combobox'

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(\'.combobox\').combobox();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest using a different plugin that meets your needs instead of hacking around the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to add a return here

```
              if (!this.selected && val !== '') {
                return; /*
                this.$element.val('');
                this.$source.val('').trigger('change');
                this.$target.val('').trigger('change');
                */
              }
```

then see what that breaks.

I then did this

```
              if (!this.selected && val !== '') {
                  console.log(val,this.source); 
                  if (this.source.indexOf(val) ==-1) {
                    this.map[prompt("value to store for "+val+"?",val)]=val;
                    this.source.push(val)
                  }
                  return; 
                  /*
                this.$element.val('');
                this.$source.val('').trigger('change');
                this.$target.val('').trigger('change');
                */
              }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bnmgjfcL/)

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan this saved me so much time.

Answer (score 1):

Try another plugin, like: https://github.com/steelheaddigital/jquery.ui.combify

To use it:

```
<select id="SomeSelect"></select>
$("#SomeSelect").combify()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wish I had found this plugin first.